# Implementation of an apache Ignite priority queue

Tags: java, queue, ignite, distributed

I need a distributed priority queue and looking through the different data structures that Apache Ignite provides I cannot find anything that resembles a priority queue. Is there anyway to create an Ignite priority queue or am I left to fetch data from the Ignite data structure and do the priority sorting myself?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: The data in your cache that you are prioritizing has a parallel Java code deployment that maintains a priority queue of the same field as you want the cache prioritized on.

Then follow this process for **get** operations:

1. Invoke get from your Java code which returns and removes the highest priority element in its queue.
2. Use that element to perform a get on the cache.

Follow this process for **put** operations:

1. Put the object into your cache taking note of the priority field.
2. Put the same priority field value into you Java implementation.

---

While the above may not be perfect under all circumstances it should perform well. Noted potential issues / assumptions:

1. Assumption that priority values are always distinct
2. There is a small and short window between when a priority item is added to the cache and when it appears in the Java priority queue. If this happened to be the next highest priority at the time it was added to the cache you might has a few milli-seconds before it actually was added to the Java code priority.
3. If your get from cache fails then your process should add the priority element back onto the Java queue implementation. Thoughts? If the Java process failed it would have to scan the cache data to set the proper priority on start up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).